# how to prevent auto-height of row in skydrive excel sheet according to text entered in a cell

Tags: excel, onedrive

I tried searching but couldn't find a solution to this very common problem.

If in a cell, I enter/paste a text worth a thousand 1000 words, then the height of the complete row increases. I just want it to be fixed, not increase according to the content entered in a cell.

Any idea where can I find this setting ?

Comment: I think what you're referring to is the Word Wrap functionality, it should be on the toolbar of the "Home" ribbon.

Comment: that worked for a cell, but how to set it default for the entire workbook ?

Comment: Glad I could help! When you paste it, try pasting just the values instead of just pasting it normally. Do this by right clicking the cell, go to Paste Special then select Values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word wrap functionality, when turned on, is what causes this. Turning it off will prevent the range from auto adjusting it's height.

*edit* To prevent it from happening when you paste, do a Paste Special -> Values or Paste Special -> Keep Text Only. Just pasting large amounts of text, depending on the formatting of the text (line breaks and such) can cause the word wrap functionality to be turned on for the cell you paste your values in.